# Cypress does not recognize step implementations in steps.js file

Tags: javascript, npm, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to create a simple test with cypress.js.
I'm able to run the cypress application with the 'npx cypress open',
and it opens cypress application where I can choose 'E2E Testing' and it has a 'configured' badge.
The component Testing feature is 'not configured'.

After choosing the E2E testing I can choose a browser (I use Chrome v110 usually), and I'm able to click
'start e2e testing in chrome' button. The cypress app shows up in a chrome window, and it lists the available
feature files and I'm also able to click on it/them.

[image]

When I click on the feature file it starts loading for a few seconds and then it fails.
On the left side of the page it shows me an error ('Step implementation missing' and few lines below: 'However, none of these files contained a step definition matching "Websites URL.".'), and on the right side I see an empty "Default blank page".

[image]
[image]

The stacktrace:

```
 at Context.eval (webpack://cypressautomation/./node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/create-tests.js:315)
From previous event:
    at Context.thenFn (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:135696:63)
    at Context.then (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:135945:21)
    at wrapped (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:151126:19)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:149985:15)
From previous event:
    at CommandQueue.runCommand (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:149951:8)
    at next (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150151:19)
From previous event:
    at next (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150151:39)
From previous event:
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:163718:77)
From previous event:
    at CommandQueue.run (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:163713:21)
    at CommandQueue.run (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150215:15)
    at $Cy.runQueue (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:151106:14)
    at cy.<computed> [as then] (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:151188:12)
    at runnable.fn (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:151367:19)
    at callFn (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104963:21)
    at ../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js.Runnable.run (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104950:7)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:158380:30)
From previous event:
    at Object.onRunnableRun (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:158363:53)
    at $Cypress.action (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:147614:28)
    at Runnable.run (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:156319:13)
    at ../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js.Runner.runTest (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105622:10)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105748:12)
    at next (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105531:14)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105541:7)
    at next (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105443:14)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105509:5)
    at timeslice (http://localhost:62221/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:99435:27)
```

The codeline in cypress that throws the exception:

```
node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/create-tests.js:315:1
  313 |                     catch (e) {
  314 |                         if (e instanceof registry_1.MissingDefinitionError) {
> 315 |                             throw new Error(createMissingStepDefinitionMessage(context, pickleStep, context.registry.parameterTypeRegistry));
      | ^
  316 |                         }
  317 |                         else {
  318 |                             throw e;
```

As I see from the errors above it can discover the feature files and also the "steps.js" (in my case loginSteps.js) but it does not recognize the step definitions inside even though it is using the correct syntax.

The package.json file:

```
{
"name": "cypressautomation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
"main": "cypress.config.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.16.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "cypress": "^12.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
}
"dependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^15.1.3",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ES2021"
    ],
    "target": "ES2021"
  }
}
```

cypress.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const webpack = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");


async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on(
      "file:preprocessor",
      webpack({
        webpackOptions: {
          plugins: [
            new NodePolyfillPlugin()
          ],
          resolve: {
            //fallback: {"path": false},
            extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
          },
          module: {
            rules: [
              {
                test: /.feature$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/webpack",
                    options: config,
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      })
  );

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config;
}
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
  "requestTimeout": 10000,
  "defaultCommandTimeout":15000,
  "pageLoadTimeOut":15000,
  "ScreenshotOnRunFailure": true,
  "trashAssetsBeforeRuns": true,
  "env":{
    "login_url":"https//www.flipkart.com/"
  }
});
```

plugins/index.js

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    // "on" is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
    // "config" is the resolved Cypress config
}
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

The file structure:
[image]

The loginSteps.js:

```
import LoginPage from "../page_objects/LoginPage";
import BasePage from "../page_objects/BasePage";
import { Given,When,Then,And } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
//const { Before, Given, When, Then, And } = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps')

const loginPage = new LoginPage();

Given("Websites URL.",() => {
     cy.visit(BasePage.url);
});
When("User fills Username.", () => {
    loginPage.fillField(BasePage.username, "username");
});
And("Fills Password.", () => {
    loginPage.fillField(BasePage.password, "valami");
});
And("Clicks login button.", () => {
    loginPage.clickButton(BasePage.loginButton);
});
Then("The login should be successful.", () => {
    loginPage.verifyLogin(LoginPage.img);
});
```

The login.feature file:

```
Feature: Login

  Scenario: Login with good credentials
    Given Websites URL.
    When User fills Username.
    And fills Password.
    And Click's login button.
    Then The login should be successful.
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Sorry if the configs are a bit messy this is the first time i'm trying to configure it and I tried many different solutions. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you test any other steps from loginSteps.js ? What contains in BasePage.url ? Why are you creating new LoginPage() but not BasePage? Maybe this is a reason. Give it a try and come back with results :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).